# PDO claims uncaught exception, even though it's inside of try/catch block?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, namespaces

Well err, I don't know what I did wrong....

This code:

```
        try {
            $this->CONN = new \PDO('mysql:dbname='.PASTEAES_DBNAME.';host='.PASTEAES_SERVER, PASTEAES_USERNAME, PASTEAES_PASSWORD);
            $this->CONN->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->raiseError('Fatal MySQL error', $e->getMessage());
        }
```

Reports this to me:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'pasteaes'' in /var/www/pasteaes/common/class.pasteaes.php on line 25`

But, as you can see it is clearly in a try and catch block.

The class that this particular piece of code is in is namespaced, which is why I used "\PDO" instead of "PDO" on line two of the code I shared above.

And oh, yeah, I know that the DB doesn't exist, but I still don't want this happening in the future (not that it will). I want to handle errors properly :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
catch(\PDOException $e)
      ^
```

Comment: Yep, just figured this out myself. Thanks anyway dewd. EDIT: 12 long minutes... I'll be back for your accepted answer.